# Apache tomcat and servlet (beginner) - 404 error, maybe classes are not found?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I'm a beginner in servlets and for a "hello world style" servlet I installed apache tomcat and created the following under it's `webapps` directory:

```
servletdir
|- index.xhtml
|- WEB-INF
   |- web.xml
   |- classes
      |- mypackage
         |- ServletClass.class
```

Initialized everything so I could access my servlet on localhost:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>mypackage.ServletClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/servleturl/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and the index.xhtml contains a form that has `action="/servleturl" method="get"`

In theory, when I start up tomcat, I should be able to access both the servlet and index.xhtml file now through `localhost:8080/servletdir/index.xhtml` and submitting the form there. Reaching index is no problem, but when I submit the form, I get a 404 error for the servlet, saying that it "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.".

My servlet class should not be the problem, it extends `HttpServlet` and overrides `doGet` to output a simple html via the `ServletResponse` parameter's `getWriter().println()`. Can an error in the servlet class cause a 404? Is my directory structure or web.xml wrong?

I have tried multiple directory structures and solutions, including:

- flat dir structure in WEB-INF and class not being in package (no "classes" directory)
- no WEB-INF, everything in servlet dir directly
- wrap WEB-INF and index.xhtml in a directory named "WebContent"
- keep "classes" directory but use no package, put class files directly into classes*

I have followed multiple resources including some tutorials and many questions here which are not directly related to my problem, but contain some info, but as I'm a complete newbie to this technology I can't deduce which resource is good and which isn't, that't why I tried almost everything I found.

The directory structure described at the top is directly on the disk as this structure, not in a war file, but as I can access some parts, I guess this isn't the problem.

*: note that I recompiled the java files with the according "package" at the file's top line every time the directory structure representing the package changed, that's not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `action="/servleturl" method="get"` to `action="/servletdir/servleturl" method="get"` or `action="servleturl" method="get"`.

with `action="/servleturl"`,you are trying to access a root relative path but  you are missing the context path `servletdir`.

If you use the `action="servleturl"`, you don't need to put the context path in the `action` as it will get it from the current url